# Category-6 cable for CCTV

Tags: ethernet, layer1, cable, utp

T568A or T568B?

Which one (1, 2, or 3)?

1. Straight-through
2. Cross-Over
3. Roll-Over

Comment: Is this residential or commercial cabling?

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. NE is a site to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks. This question is severely lacking in detail needed to answer the question, doesn't exhibit a minimum level of knowledge that would be present in a professionally managed network, and/or no effort/research on a very basic topic.Please edit your question and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

If this is residential cabling, it is off-topic here, but you should familiarize yourself with [ANSI/TIA/EIA-570-B Residential Telecommunications Infrastructure Standard](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwjjzaHXjsTLAhUhsoMKHaPvAboQFggvMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vyskocil.net%2Ffirma%2Fdokumenty%2Fdownload.asp%3Fid%3D156&usg=AFQjCNEQ730yEmB8aUxvAAvQSiqA_YROyg&sig2=C44KwaZ8SMPjf0Lues6O3g&cad=rja).

If this is commercial cabling, the usual is T568B, but either could be used, as long as *all* cabling is done the same. The standard calls for straight-through cabling from end-to-end on a cable run for UTP cabling (fiber is crossed-over). All crossover or rollover, splitting, etc. *must* be done outside of the WAO (Work Area Outlet).